Applying CSS filter property to PDF generated with WeasyPrint
I'm using the WeasyPrint library to generate a PDF from HTML and CSS.
In my HTML, I have the following structure:
<div class="icon">
  <div style="background-color: var(--mediumIcon);">
    <div style="background-color: var(--mediumList);">
      <p>Medium</p>
      <num style="filter: blur(8px);">18</num>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

I'm applying the blur(8px) filter to the  element to blur the number. However, when I generate the PDF, the blur effect is not applied to the number.
